# Game Center Authentication issue on iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, game-center

I am trying to understand Game Center and have written a small implementation that seems to work when I deploy it to my iPhone5 (running iOS7). However, when I run the same code (debug deploy) to my iPhone 6+ (iOS8.3) or iPad (iOS8.3) is simply won't authenticate.  Even when I log in to Game Center with a sandbox account before running the code it still doesn't recognise I am logged in!

I am using Xamarin so the code is c#..

This is the authentication code:

```
 public static void setAuthenticateHandler()
    {
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(6, 0))
        {
            GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.AuthenticateHandler = (ui, error) =>
            {
                if (ui != null)
                {
                    GameCenterManager._controller.PresentViewController(ui, true, null);
                }
                else if (GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated)
                {
                    if (currentPlayerID != null || currentPlayerID != GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.PlayerID)
                        currentPlayerID = GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.PlayerID;

                    if (AfterAuthentication != null)
                        AfterAuthentication();
                }
                else
                {
                    var alert = new UIAlertView("Game Center Account Required", "Login to the game center!", null, "Retry", null);
                    alert.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        //GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated();
                    };
                    alert.Show();
                }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            var authenticatedHandler = new Action<NSError> ((error) => {
                if (GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated)
                {
                    if (currentPlayerID != null || currentPlayerID != GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.PlayerID)
                        currentPlayerID = GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.PlayerID;

                    if (AfterAuthentication != null)
                        AfterAuthentication();
                }
                else
                {
                    var alert = new UIAlertView("Game Center Account Required", "Login to the game center!", null, "Retry", null);
                    alert.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        setAuthenticateHandler();
                    };
                    alert.Show();

                }
            });
            GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticate(authenticatedHandler);

        }
    }
```

Few questions:

1. I presume the `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(6, 0)` call simply returns true if the iOS is major version 6 or higher?
2. Can I run this static method multiple times - knowing that after specifying the AuthenticateHandler it will perform an immediate gamecenter check?
3. Now for the **MAIN ISSUE** - when running this in debug on the simulator (iOS8.2) all is fine and the `GameCenterManager._controller.PresentViewController(ui, true, null);` is called if I am not logged onto GC yet - so all ok.  Also on my iPhone5 (iOS7) this works well and the `GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated` is called if I already were logged on.  However, on my other devices that run iOS8.3 it jumps straight to the alert window and that's it - irrespective if I am already logged on or not.

Note: I read people suggesting to switch on the Sandbox switch in my Setting -> GameCenter -> Sandbox but this isn't there on my iphone 5, 6+ and ipad - it's just not there?...

Any help much appreciated - this is driving me nuts!

Comment: Have you cancelled the game center sign in? If you do it multiple times it will not show, and you have to sign in through the game center app before launching your app.

Comment: The GC sign in form never pops up - that is the problem!! That is, only on iOS 8.3 - on my iPhone5 (running iOS7) everything is fine.

Comment: @Marcel:  Do you have the code that does these 2 things: (1) First, check to see if the user is signed in to Game Center and (2) if the user has not signed in to Game Center yet, then it pops up the logon window for Game Center so that the user can sign in ? If you have that code, please share with us because we need something like that. Thank you so much. (BTW, I am also using C# and Xamarin to develop games).